# A Hashmap bucket can contain different hashcoded object. If so How hashmap achieves O(1)

Tags: java, hashmap, time-complexity, hashcode

Hi I am trying to understand how hashmap working . Hashmap works based on hasing principle .

My doubt is I**s it possible to contain different hashcoded object in same bucket** ? If it is possible means how **get(key) achieves O(1) time** ? Because based on the hashcode and hashing , Bucket will be found . but One have to iterate  through elements right . Then how it will be O(1).

**For example**
My Bucket size is 4
I am going to put elements "X"( hashcode - 3) , "Y" ( hashcode - 7) , "Z"( hashcode - 11) . All these three elements bucket location will be 3 . If I am calling get("Z") means It have to traverse through elements in the bucket then only it can find . Then Then how it will be O(1).

Please anyone help me to clear my doubt. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the hashmap lookup algorithm works like this:

1. Derive an integer hash value from the object - `O(1)`
2. Locate the bucket for that hash - `O(1)`
3. Find the object in that bucket - `O(number of collided hashes in that bucket)`

Although the `number of collided hashes in that bucket` can increase towards `n` under extreme circumstances (such as *we only have one bucket*) those circumstances are not considered when deriving the `O`ness of the algorithm. This value is considered to be `1` because increasing `n` does not affect it's cost even lineraly under **normal** circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `get(Key)`s *time-complexity* of `HashMap` is NOT always `O(1)`. `O(1)` is the ideal case.

`HashMap` has an Array of instances `Entry`. HashCode of the object determines in which index of this array a "new entry" should go. If 2 Objects have to get into the same bucket / index (if there is a collision), then a `LinkedList` is used and the new Entry is added to the `LinkedList`. 
Worst case, all enteries could map to the same index (if there is only one bucket) and the time complexity will be `O(n)`.

Comment: From Java8, if the particular bucket contains 8 nodes or more, then the linked list is transformed into Tree. then the time complexity will be O(log(n)).